# Why does my zsh shell show me as user: git:(master)?

Tags: terminal, git, zsh

I can't for the life of me, figure out why my zsh shell shows me as a user:git and in the master branch. It was on the gh-pages branch, after messing around with some git commands like git checkout. Is this normal? I don't understand what's happening. If I type in git master, I also get back lots of directories and files of a very old project. I'm still not totally comfortable in the terminal, but I have graduated to zsh in my opinion, but this is definitely an obstacle. An example screenshot is attached.

PS - if I run the whoami command, I do get back my username.